# Setting totalPages in Ag-grid pagination

Tags: angular, angular5, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid with pagination.

I am looking for a way to set the total number of pages for pagination with the **count/pageSize** way.

The data should be loaded on event **onPaginationChanged**

Something like :

```
 this.gridOptions.api.setTotalPages = 10
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what you need and what you have achieved till now. Your question is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to set the `total number of pages` in ag-grid by using `rowModelType: infinite` row model with `pagination: true` to achieve the same effect:

See this example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#example-block-equal-page

Key point here is to set `lastRow` equal to totalCount of pages you get from server and pass it into `params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);` In this way ag-grid would know total number of pages in advance and show the total count in pagination control.

```
    const dataSource = {
        rowCount: null,
        getRows: function(params) {
          console.log(
            'asking for ' + params.startRow + ' to ' + params.endRow
          );
          let pageNum = Math.round(params.endRow / PAGE_SIZE);
          fetchPage(pageNum).then(page => {
            var rowsThisPage = page.entities;
            var lastRow = page.paging.totalCount;
            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
          });
        }
    };
    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct api/parameter to set number of pages. But you can alter `paginationPageSize` to make sure you have 10 pages at max.

Let's assume you have can minimum 50 per page.

```
var gridOptions = {
   ...
   pagination: true,
   paginationPageSize: 50,
   ...
};
```

Then you may have some method which sets the data

```
setDataToGrid: function(data){
    //data is more than your what can be fit in 10 pages
    if(data.length > gridOptions.paginationPageSize * 10){
        gridOptions.paginationPageSize = Math.ceil(data.length/10);
    }
    gridOptions.api.setRowData(data);
}
```

[working plnkr example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IrtR6k8HeanOqGKDOpjt?p=preview)

Note: It's not nice to always distribute to ten pages unless you have considerable amount of rows which can't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Giving Example in Vue js
First add :-

```
 <v-select
              v-bind:items="pageSize"
              v-model="pageModel"
              label="PageSize"
              v-on:change="onPageSizeChanged(pageModel)"
              id="page-size"
              style="width:115px;max-height: 32px;text-align:right !important;  
              float: right;
              margin-right: 283px;
              margin-top:10px;"

            ></v-select>
```

Then  Add in methods

/** use of page size to setting pagination */

```
 onPageSizeChanged(newPageSize) {
      this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(parseInt(newPageSize));
    },
```